# ICS Android system-server died after put sign-error

Tags: android, build, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-source

Him I'm now trying to build my own ICS system image (from android-native source 4.0.3_r1 branch), and I can get adb message now, but somehow system-server died because of signing error in booting time

```
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755): Exception reading AndroidManifest.xml in /system/framework/framework-res.apk
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755): java.lang.SecurityException: /system/framework/framework-res.apk failed verification of META-INF/CERT.SF
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.failedVerification(JarVerifier.java:136)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:305)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:258)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:378)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:362)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:512)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.collectCertificatesLI(PackageManagerService.java:2806)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:2895)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanDirLI(PackageManagerService.java:2750)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.(PackageManagerService.java:1053)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
    01-01 08:41:52.689: ERROR/PackageParser(7755): Package android has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring!
    01-01 08:41:52.689: INFO/PackageManager(7755): /system/app/HTMLViewer.apk changed; collecting certs
    01-01 08:41:52.689: WARN/PackageManager(7755): Failed verifying certificates for package:android
    01-01 08:41:52.699: WARN/PackageParser(7755): Exception reading AndroidManifest.xml in /system/app/HTMLViewer.apk
    01-01 08:41:52.699: WARN/PackageParser(7755): java.lang.SecurityException: /system/app/HTMLViewer.apk failed verification of META-INF/CERT.SF
    01-01 08:41:52.699: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.failedVerification(JarVerifier.java:136)
    01-01 08:41:52.699: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(JarVerifier.java:305)
    01-01 08:41:52.699: WARN/PackageParser(7755):     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(JarVerifier.java:258)
```

As you see, main android apk cannot be loaded because it seems doesn't have proper key,
but I found all apks in system image is signed, and my java version is 1.6.2_64bit so there should be no problem

```
    
    jhb@ARND1B7:~/android-4.0.3_r1/out/debug/target/product/android/system/framework$ jarsigner -verify framework-res.apk
    jar verified.
    jhb@ARND1B7:~/android-4.0.3_r1/out/debug/target/product/android/system/framework$ java -version
    java version "1.6.0_26"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

The one suspicious thing is , build property. 
I build android exactly like this,
(this prompt put out on screen when you build

```
jhb@ARND1B7:~/android-4.0.3_r1$ make -j12 PRODUCT-android-eng
    ============================================
    PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
    PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
    TARGET_PRODUCT=android
    TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
    TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=debug
    TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
    TARGET_ARCH=arm
    TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
    HOST_ARCH=x86
    HOST_OS=linux
    HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
    BUILD_ID=ITL41D
    ============================================
```

Do I have to add some property on my AndroidProduct.mk? or what should I do?
Any answer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following process. Run:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
```

You will see all possible targets. Then if you build for android emulator:

```
lunch full-eng
```

And

```
make -j12
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what cause this, it was about init.rc on ramdisk image

In init.rc file, we defined BOOTCLASSPATH for boot android

If we use ICS, BOOTCLASSPATH variable should be different like this

```
export ANDROID_BOOTLOGO 1
export BOOTCLASSPATH /system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
```